# Setting data of one class from within another class

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to set the attendance of students based on user input. Where I run it to the problem is trying to take that input and assign it to my data on each student.

All the data I have is read from a file in to a singly linked list. The struct for this data type is declared in my node.h.

So what I'm asking is how would I modify the values that originate from the Node class, within my menu class?

**Menu.cpp**

```
   void Menu::chooseMenu(ifstream *input, List L1)
{
    data temp;
    //data plswork[12];
    char holder[30];
    char junk[30];
    int i=1,j=1;

    do{
    system("cls");
    cout<<"1. Import"<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Load Master"<<endl;
    cout<<"3. Store Master"<<endl;
    cout<<"4. Mark Absence"<<endl;
    cout<<"5. Generate Report"<<endl;
    cout<<"6. Exit"<<endl;
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cin>>selection;

    if(selection == 1)//import
    {
        while(!input->eof())
        {
            memset(holder,0,30);

            if(i==3 && j != 1)
            {
                input->getline(holder,30,'"');
                input->getline(holder,30,'"');
                input->getline(junk,30,',');
            }
            else
            {
                input->getline(holder,30,',');
            }

            if(i==1)
            {
                strcpy(temp.record, holder);
                //cout<<temp.record<<endl;
                i++;
            }
            else if(i==2)
            {
                strcpy(temp.ID, holder);
                //cout<<temp.ID<<endl;
                i++;
            }
            else if(i==3)
            {
                strcpy(temp.name, holder);//read between quotes
                //cout<<temp.name<<endl;
                i++;
                j=2;
            }
            else if(i==4)
            {
                strcpy(temp.email, holder);
                //cout<<temp.email<<endl;
                i++;
            }
            else if(i==5)
            {
                strcpy(temp.units, holder);
                //cout<<temp.units<<endl;
                i++;
            }
            else if(i==6)
            {
                strcpy(temp.major, holder);
                //cout<<temp.major<<endl;
                i++;
            }
            else if(i==7)
            {
                strcpy(temp.grade, holder);

                //cout<<temp.grade<<endl;
                L1.insertOrder(temp);
                i=1;
            }

        }
    }

    else if(selection == 2)//load master
    {

    }

    else if(selection == 3)//store master
    {

    }

    else if(selection == 4)//mark absence
    {
        while(L1.nextPtr() != NULL)
        {
        char name;
            cout<<"Bruce :"<<L1.getDataL().absent<<endl;
            cout<<"Is "<<L1.getDataL().name<<" present? (Y/N)"<<endl;
            cin>>name;
            if(name == 'y' || name == 'Y')
            {
                L1.setAtt(L1.getDataL(),1); // This is where I try to set attendance to 0 or 1. 
                cout<<L1.getDataL().absent<<endl;
            }
            else
            {
                L1.setAtt(L1.getDataL(),0);
            }

            L1.nextPtr();
            system("pause");
        }
    }

    else if(selection == 5)//gen report
    {

    }

    }while(selection != 6);

}
```

**Node.cpp**

```
#include "Node.h"

ListNode::ListNode (ListNode &copyObject)
{
    this->mData = copyObject.mData;
    this->mpNext = copyObject.mpNext;
}

ListNode::~ListNode ()
{
    // does nothing
    cout << "exiting listnode object - going out of scope" << endl;
}

ListNode * ListNode::getNextPtr () const
{
    return mpNext;
}

data ListNode::getData() const
{
    return mData;
}

ListNode::ListNode(data newData)
{
    mData = newData;
    this->mpNext = NULL;
}
```

**List.h**

```
#include "Node.h"

#ifndef LinkedList_H
#define LinkedList_H
using std::ostream;

class List
{
    friend ostream & operator << (ostream &lhs, List &rhs);
    friend ListNode;

    public:
        List ();
        List (List &copyObject);
        ~List ();

        List & operator = (List &rhs);

        ListNode *makeNode (data newNode);
        bool insertOrder (data Node);
        bool deleteNode (data Node);
        data getDataL();
        ListNode *nextPtr();
        void setAtt(int atten);




    private:
        ListNode *pHead;
};
#endif
```

**ListNode.h**

```
#ifndef ListNode_H
#define ListNode_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

struct data
    {
        char record[8];
        char ID[12];
        char name[30];
        char email[30];
        char units[6];
        char major[8];
        char grade[14];
        int absent;
        char dateabsent[32];
    };


class List;


class ListNode
{
    friend class List;
    friend struct data;
    public:
        ListNode();
        ListNode(data newData);
        //ListNode(char newrecord[], string newID, string newname, string newemail, string newunits, string newmajor, string newgrade);
        ListNode(ListNode &copyObject);
        ~ListNode();

        data getData() const;
        ListNode *getNextPtr() const;

        ListNode & operator = (ListNode &rhs);

    private:
        data mData;
        ListNode *mpNext;
};
#endif
```

Comment: Please post the headers for `List` and `ListNode` so that we have a better idea of how your program works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so, you're going to have a real tough time getting any good answers with that code because your data structure is not very well constructed, you only need one class, maybe two, to do this.  Bellow is the two class declaration:

```
struct data
{
    char record[8];
    char ID[12];
    char name[30];
    char email[30];
    char units[6];
    char major[8];
    char grade[14];
    int absent;
    char dateabsent[32];
};
class listNode
{
    listNode* next;
    data data;

public:
    listNode(data& d);    //Will copy d into data, you will need to define
    listNode();           //Will initialize a blank data, you will need to define
    ~listNode();          //Definitely need a destructor

    data& getMutableData();
    const data& getImutableData() const;

    void insert(listNode* n);
    bool delete(listNode* n);
    listNode* next();

};
```

The wrapper class you have is really unnecessary for a linked list, and you want to pass large data structures either as pointers or by reference, you should never return "data", only "data*" and "data&".  "data" should be reserved for the creation of new objects only.  The implementation of a few important functions here:

```
void listNode::insert(listNode* n)
{
    if(next!=NULL)
        next->insert(n);
    else
        next = n;
}
bool listNode::delete(listNode* n)
{
    if(next==NULL)
        return false;
    if(next == n)
    {
        listNode* temp = next;
        next = next->next();
        delete temp;
        return true;
    }
    return next->delete(n);
}
```

The reason you're having trouble is basically that your data structures are very poorly implemented, they need a redesign.  What I have above is by no means the only or even the best implementation (notably, there is little encapsulation or data protection), but it appears to be close to the singly-linked list functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah I kinda noticed that as I went along, but this is my first project I had to intermingle between classes. The hardest part for me is getting in to the private data of another class.

Comment: You need an accessor function to do that.  The whole point of private members is that they aren't visible to the outside, you need to return them from a function.  In general, you shouldn't use "friend'...make an accessor function!

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea how your `setAtt` method on `List` is supposed to work. So without using `setAtt`, one solution is to make `getDataL` return `data *` (a pointer to the data struct). Now your main holds a pointer to some data in the linked list, and can modify it as needed.

Comment: setAtt was my attempt at setting the value. Doing this won't change the value that is within the linked list, will it?

Comment: No, not if `setAtt` is changing the return value of `getDataL`